# Book recommendations on measures of entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement

I am an undergrad. physics student writing my bachelor thesis at the moment.

What book would you recommend that talks about measures of entanglement? It would be really cool if it gave different possible such measures (they only resolve into the von-Neumann entropy in a special case). Specifically for bi-partite states, but also with more particles involved, like GHZ states.

For example, the Prof. mentioned holographic entanglement entropy.

It would be cool if my reference were something other than wikipedia, but the papers referenced there are often over my head. So a book, which goes into detail, but is sort of didactic at the same time would be awesome!

I hope it will be available online, but that will be my problem to worry about.

Comment: How about review articles?

Answer (score 1):

A classic review which gives an overview over a broad range of entanglement measures for pure and mixed states is 
[M. Plenio, S. Virmani: An introduction to entanglement measures](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163).